# How to generate sports tracking data using deep learning?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, time-series, gan

**Data**: I have a 2D Numpy array that contains tracking data for football. Each row has the (x,y) coordinates for all players + the ball. That's 22 players and 1 ball = 46 columns. The frequency is 0.1 seconds i.e., every row shows everything's positions 0.1 seconds after the previous row. I have a total of a few thousand such arrays.

**My Goal**:
I was thinking of generating artificial data based upon these sequences. I got the original idea from this paper - [Generating Play-by-Play Basketball Data](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.07088)

**What I've tried** My initial efforts were with a GAN. Since it was already a 2D array, I thought I could convert it to images and then use a GAN to generate images based on them (I'd read a lot about GANs to generate faces and handwritten digits). However, that didn't work out for me. Here's what any one of the actual real images look like -

[image]

And here's what the generated image looks like (after 29000 epochs) -

[image]

Obviously, a lot of noise

*The dimensions are all 46x46 which is why the pictures are so tiny.*

I read up a bit and from what I understood, generating temporal data is slightly different from normal images so I'm back to square one.

If someone could suggest some ideas to help me in understanding -

- ***What's a general idea to go about achieving this task with GANs (temporal sequential data instead of image arrays)***,
- ***What generative models/ networks/architectures could I use to do so***,
- Any other tips/suggestions as well.